# Bash check if nvm installed

Tags: bash, nvm

How can I detirmine if nvm (Node Version Manager) is installed in bash?

I already have it installed in my system but I haven't been able to make any bash script that can detect it. I am making a script that should be used by others which depends on nvm, so I want to output if it's not installed and exit if it isn't..

This doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26759734/846348 it says that nvm isn't installed but the bash script can use nvm..

Would be nice if it supported Mac Terminal, Mac iTerm and Windows with Linux shell at least.

Comment: `nvm` is a actually a shell function and thus the test in the linked answer cannot work since `command -v nvm` doesn't return a file path.

Comment: @FelixKling works for me and seemingly others also.. can't attach a screenshot here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one can check with `command -v nvm`:

```
$ command -v nvm >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "nvm is required, but it's not installed.  Aborting."; exit 1; }
```

Comment: which nvm returns empty for me..  which nvm ; echo $? returns 1

Comment: `command -v nvm >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "nvm is required, but it's not installed.  Aborting."; exit 1; }
nvm is required, but it's not installed.  Aborting.
logout
Saving session...completed.

[Process completed]`

Comment: seems like I have destroyed it somehow now :P

Comment: @OZZIE `which` should not return empty, but should complain it's not on `$PATH` and even list the whole `$PATH`; it's probably not properly installed, when it is not on `$PATH`. `command -v` is the most reliable way to check.

Comment: I added `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` to my `~/.bash_profile` and nvm came back,, no idea how I managed to destroy it :P perhaps something I ran somehow removed it from $PATH :S no idea..

Comment: @MartinZeitler command you suggested to OP returns 1 as status code for me when I use it in script. But when I use it in command line all is OK. Any Idea what I am missing?


(sorry for bumping an old thread)

Comment: @ZuBB I don't understand the problem. please see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Comment: Hi @MartinZeitler.

In script when I use check mentioned above (with help of `command` shell's built in command I always get `1` as return code and it means that `nvm` executable is not found. while same command run`ned in command prompt produces valid result (0 for case when nvm exists and 1 for case when it does not)).

Any idea what can be wrong with my setup? (OS, particular shell or its version, etc) I have tested both on mac+bash3.2 and ubuntu 16.04 LTS + bash 4.4

Answer (score 4):

The [nvm install script](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/install.sh) checks if nvm is installed using roughly the following logic:

```bash
if [ -d "${HOME}/.nvm/.git" ]; then echo "nvm installed"; else echo "nvm not installed"; fi
```

This just checks if the directory `~/.nvm/.git` exists.

To exit with failure if the directory `~/.nvm/.git` does not exist, you could use:

```bash
if [ ! -d "${HOME}/.nvm/.git" ]; then exit; fi
```

#### Check if nvm installed using a Makefile

```
NVM_EXISTS := $(shell if [ -d "${HOME}/.nvm/.git" ]; then echo "nvm installed"; fi)

.PHONY: check
check:
ifndef NVM_EXISTS
    $(error Please install nvm: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)
endif
```

#### Note on nvm install.sh

The actual install script uses the following functions to determine the nvm installation directory (rather than assuming `${HOME}/.nvm`). But if you are using the default location `${HOME}/.nvm`, you can skip these checks.

```bash
nvm_default_install_dir() {
  [ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm"
}

nvm_install_dir() {
  if [ -n "$NVM_DIR" ]; then
    printf %s "${NVM_DIR}"
  else
    nvm_default_install_dir
  fi
}
```